# Removing Identical Polylines in multiple feature classes

Tags: arcgis-10.5

I have ~35 topo line files which show change in topography over time. 75% of the lines are identical since there was no change over the time period. I am trying to extract the portions of each file which have changed and delete the lines that are identical. Is there a way to batch process this?